# Accessing HTML attributes inside Listener Function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access a custom HTML attribute from within a function attached to an event listener but so far have been unable to get it to work. I'm not sure how to correctly reference the target element.

Currently I have:

```
<td id= "kayak1" data-picid="1"><img src= "thumbnail.jpg"></td>
```

A listener:

```
var cat1 = document.getElementById("kayak1");
cat1.addEventListener("dblclick", showCatPix);
```

And my function:

```
function showCatPix () {
    var picSelect = this.getAttribute("data-picid");
    switch(picSelect) {
        case 1:
            var catPix = document.getElementById("showCatPics");
            catPix.src ="cat_kayak.jpg";
            break;
    }
}
```

The event is calling the function correctly but showCatPix isn't accessing the picid attribute and nothing is being displayed. I also tried using this.dataset.picid. But that didn't work either. Any tips on how to correctly reference the property would be great.

Comment: `function showCatPix()` change to `function showCatPix(e)`, and `e.target.dataset.picid`, and Mew in celebration.

Comment: Where is the ID "showCatPics" in your HTML?

Comment: It's probably because, in your function, 'this' isn't the element being clicked. When you add a listener, your function accepts one parameter as the event. Then, inside your function, you can access the element being clicked through `e.target`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `picSelect` retrieved from DOM attribute is string `"1"`, while in `switch` statement you are comparing it with number `1`. And `switch/case` is a `===` comparison.

---

Using `this` is not an issue, it should work.

Comment: 1. Was my problem. Thanks a lot : )

Comment: The ID was in my HTML. As soon as I changed the comparison in the switch case everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an event listener, the callback function, in this case `showCatPix` will receive the event in parameter. The event has a `target` attribute, which is the DOM element on which the event occured. In this case your td.

For details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Answer (score 0):

This shows generally how to access data attributes.

```js
var cat1 = document.getElementById("kayak1");
cat1.addEventListener("dblclick", showCatPix);

function showCatPix(e) {
  var picSelect = e.target.dataset.picid; // <-- key bit right here
  console.log(e.target.dataset.picid);
  switch (+picSelect) { // <-- coerce to number
    case 1:             // also consider mapping an array of functions instead of a 
      alert('Meow!');   // switch, a personal maintainability preference of mine
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="kayak1" data-picid="1" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
```